# Why is grep showing "near" duplicate lines with a different beginning here?

Tags: linux, grep

I'm running this grep command from a directory containing a bunch of sub-directories:

grep -rn 'AlertManager.ShowAlert'

This works, but I see that every result is being duplicated. The first set of results only has "=" followed by a number (maybe a cumulative total of all lines checked?) and the second set has what I'd prefer, the full path of the file followed by the line number in the file.

Why am I getting the first set of "=:#####" results, and can I suppress those results?

First set:

```
=:15625:gui/alertmanager.gui:72:            visible = "[And(AlertManager.HasCallForPeace, AlertManager.ShowAlert('call_for_peace'))]"
=:15628:gui/alertmanager.gui:94:            visible = "[And(AlertManager.HasTrueWar, AlertManager.ShowAlert('war'))]"

... middle cut for brevity ...
```

Start of second set (I left the last line of the first set in for comparison):

```
=:15787:gui/alertmanager.gui:1180:          visible = "[And(AlertManager.HasGreatWorkWithUpgradableEffects, AlertManager.ShowAlert('gw_with_upgrades'))]"
gui/alertmanager.gui:72:            visible = "[And(AlertManager.HasCallForPeace, AlertManager.ShowAlert('call_for_peace'))]"
gui/alertmanager.gui:94:            visible = "[And(AlertManager.HasTrueWar, AlertManager.ShowAlert('war'))]"
```

Comment: Do you have `=:15628:gui` directory?

Comment: And post output of `type -a grep` and try with `--color=never` option.

Answer (score 1):

After some helpful comments above - turns out it's my mistake!

There's a file named "=" which happens to have the same content in it! It was bizarre enough that I assumed it was something grep was doing, but it's not.

So I guess my "answer" is to get grep to skip that particular file.

Comment: That file would have the output of an earlier run of `grep` right? Since it contains the filenames and line numbers of the actual matches too (`gui/alertmanager.gui:72:` etc.)

Comment: Hm that's a good point maybe I piped to a file by accident at some point.

Comment: You should probably just delete that file then.

Comment: Yep, it's trashed. Was able to confirm it for sure when I noticed the last line was truncated. Clearly I did some typo and had to CTRL+C out of some big mess it was creating. :) If nobody had pointed that out it might have taken a while for me to think of that.