# Using grep to recursively search in a directory, ignoring a single file

Tags: grep

Is there a way to get grep to search an entire directory, but ignore matches in ONE file?

The command I'm using is:

```
grep -rn 'SearchTextHere'
```

The file I need to ignore has a weird filename: `=`.

Yes, the file name is just an equals sign. Yeah, I don't get it either.

(Not sure if it's supposed to be there or not, so I can't just delete it. I don't think it's an accidental grep piped to a file or anything like that.)

grep version 3.4

Comment: With GNU grep you should be able to use the `--exclude` option ex. `--exclude==`

Comment: Yeah I saw that in the man page, but I've had trouble getting it to actually work. :) Actually I think I tried "exclude-from" - not really clear on the difference.

Comment: We established yesterday that your`=` file was the accidental output from a previous `grep`, so it is unlikely to be of any significance. Check the owner and date to see if that enlightens you. Then move it somewhere like `~/ProbableGarbage` in case you really ever need it. Having a filename of `=` is almost certainly a typo of a command option (= being next to - on the keyboard) and it might still be in your shell history if you want to investigate. Obfuscating a script to deal with a previous error will never come to an end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like steeldriver's comment suggestion works:

```
grep -rn 'SearchTextHere' --exclude==
```

Or I guess for a normal filename it'd be

```
grep -rn 'SearchTextHere' --exclude=FileToIgnore
```

I was trying to use "--exclude-from" from the man page. No idea what that's for.

Comment: `--exclude-from` does `--exclude` for every filename listed in another file. So if you had 10 exclusions rather than listing them one by one on the command line you could pop them into a file and exclude-from that file

Comment: Ahhhh, so it meant a file literally, I took it to mean "name of the file" you're excluding. Overlooked --exclude entirely, maybe because it has the bizarre sounding GLOB term after it.

Comment: The word "_glob_" means a pattern that can contain shell wildcards used for matching filenames. It's not a Regular Expression. For example, `*.txt` is a glob as is `file.???` and even `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 2):

`=`-named files can appear if one does:

```
[ a >= b ]
```

or:

```
expr a >= b
```

by mistake as that's essentially the same as:

```
[ a b ] > '='
expr a b > '='
```

That is running those `[` or `expr` commands with their output redirected to `=`. As `>` is a redirection operator in the syntax of the shell, `>` should be quoted:

```
expr a '>=' b
```

```
[ a '>=' b ]
```

(though few `[` implementations support a `>=` operator; `yash`'s builtin `[` does)

If that `=` file of yours is empty, that's one possible explanation.

Now to exclude any file called `=` in a recursive search with GNU `grep`, you'd use:

```
grep -rn --exclude== SearchTextHere .
```

Or:

```
grep -rn --exclude = SearchTextHere .
```

`--exclude-from` is for when you want to give the list of exclusion in a file. Here, while you could do:

```
echo = | grep --exclude-from=/dev/stdin -rn SearchTextHere .
```

That has no advantage over using `--exclude`.

In any case, there's no way to tell GNU `grep -r` to exclude only the one `=` in the current directory (and still search in the `=` files found in other subdirectories). For that, you could use `find` to find the files and exclude `=` and let it call `grep` to search the text within the files, as you'd do anyway standardly as `-r` is not a standard `grep` option.

```
find . ! -path './=' -type f -exec grep -n SearchTextHere /dev/null {} +
```

(the added `/dev/null` to guarantee `grep` will always print the names of the files even if `find` finds only one file; with GNU `grep`, you can also use the `-H` option for that).

Or to skip *directories* called `=` and any files within (which `grep --exclude =` doesn't do):

```
find . -name = -prune -o -type f -exec grep -rn /dev/null {} +
```

(here skipping *any* file/dir called `=`. Use `-path ./=` to only skip the `=` directory in in the current directory).

Comment: FWIW, it wasn't mentioned here, but in their other question, it looked like that `=` file contained the output of an earlier grep run: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/665652/170373 I couldn't come up with a plausible explanation for that...

Comment: @ilkkachu I suppose that could be the result of a `grep -rn >= something`

Comment: I just double checked that stupid "=" file. I'm pretty sure now that it was some clumsy grep typo I did at some point, and had to CTRL+C out of. I checked the last line of the file and clearly writing it was interrupted at some point. :)